# Why CBCharacteristic is not updating on each write calls?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Whenever, I am performing a write operation, I have a call of below method: it works! but the problem is that, even if I will be making different calls it will always showing me the output of last result. I am not getting an updated values for the specific commands.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {...}
```

To fix this, if we disconnect and then reconnects to the peripheral it will be with updated results.

Couldn't understanding what's wrong happened here?

Is it related to `CBCharacteristic` object? Can we refresh it? Do we need to refresh a peripheral?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you mean that the peripheral object isn't showing the updated data, or the value associated with the characteristic in your app isn't showing the updated data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only updating if I will restart my BT device. Hence, the answer is short but it took 1 hour for me to get an update on this.